# How to segregate communities detected in a graph?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I have detected the communities from a given graph but I can't segregate them into individual components so that I can find the properties of the communities.
As I have clarified in the comments section, "If there are 4 communities in a given graph, say in a social network, I want to analyze each community individually. How can I do this?"

Comment: Is this not `FindGraphCommunities` ?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "segregate them". Please explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: If there are 4 communities in a given graph, say in a social network, I want to analyze each community individually. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you just looking for `Subgraph`? Note that in versions before 12.0, `Subgraph` discards all properties. As a workaround, you can use [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM)'s `IGWeightedSubgraph` to keep edge weights, or `IGTakeSubgraph` to keep all properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to extract the largest strongly connected component and analyze it.

```
sa = SparseArray[{{0, 3, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 1}, {1, 3, 0, 1, 
0}, {1, 4, 0, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 
0, 0}}];
gr = Graph[sa["NonzeroPositions"], EdgeWeight -> sa["NonzeroValues"], 
DirectedEdges -> True, 
PlotLabel -> \[Theta]1 <= Subscript[m, ij] < \[Theta]2, 
VertexLabels -> "Name"]
SCCs = ConnectedComponents[gr];
sccLargest = MaximalBy[Length]@SCCs // Flatten;
eCountSCClargest = EdgeCount[Subgraph[gr, sccLargest]];
densitySCClargest = (eCountSCClargest/(Length[
   sccLargest // Flatten]^2 - 
   Length[sccLargest // Flatten])) // N;
grSCClargest = 
Subgraph[gr, sccLargest, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
EdgeWeight -> {e_ :> PropertyValue[{gr, e}, EdgeWeight]}, 
EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center, Round[#, .001] &]]
```